# Why are not previosuly entered values shown in my EDIT form?

Tags: php, forms, netbeans, crud

I am working on PHP CRUD operations and I have created a basic edit form in PHP. I have not used any field validations and all I want is simply editing information.

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/page__st__0)

Once a user is clicked on Edit link he is directed to the following form on which the user is supposed to edit his data.

Here is the code

```
<?php
include_once './functions.php';
include_once './database.php';


function renderForm($firstName,$lastName,$age){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Edit</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="edit.php" method="post">
            First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php $firstName ;?>"><br/>
            Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php $lastName ;?>"><br/>
            Age<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php $age ;?>"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
            <a href="main_menu.php">Cancel</a>


        </form>
   <?php
}
   ?>

        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $firstName = cleanData($_POST['firstname']);
            $lastName = cleanData($_POST['lastname']);
            $age = (int) $_POST['age'];
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $query = "UPDATE basic ";
            $query.="SET first_name='$firstName',last_name='$lastName',age=$age ";
            $query.="WHERE id=$id";

            confirmQuery($query);
            closeDatabase();

        }else{
            $id=cleanData($_GET['id']);

            $query="SELECT * FROM basic WHERE id= {$id} ";
            $result=confirmQuery($query);

            $rows=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $firstName=$rows['first_name'];
            $lastName=$rows['last_name'];
            $age=$rows['age'];

            renderForm($firstName, $lastName, $age);

        }
        ?>


    </body>
</html>

 //Additional information
//functions included in other files
function cleanData($input){
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$input);
}

function confirmQuery($query){
    global $connection;
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result){
        return "Query failed : ".mysqli_error($connection);
    }
    else{
        return $result;
    }
}
function closeDatabase(){
    global $connection;
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
       //I have not included the file which I am using to 
//connect to the DB. I am sure there is no error with that file since it works 
//properly with other php files
```

The problem that I have with my edit form is it does not show previously entered data and just shows only a blank form (similar to create form). (It does not happen when I run the demo in the above mentioned tutorial)

Netbenas IDE says **variables which are inside HTML input tags seems to be unused in its scope**. I have googled this question and found that warning can be simply ignored.

But Where have I gone wrong?
I am grateful to anyone who can kindly go through my code and show me the error.

Thank You :)

Comment: I can only assume the variables you are passing to your `renderForm` function are blank. Have you tried to echo the variables before you call the function?

Comment: @superphonic - Thanks. I used echo statements and all my data pulled out from the DB were displayed as I expected. How did you assume it?

Comment: You didn't echo the variables in the input elements.

Comment: @Gil - I have echoed them under value attribute  First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php $firstName ;?>">

Comment: You called the variable in PHP but didn't echo it into the HTML. Change it to `echo $firstName;` and you should see it in the generated HTML. I'm guessing this is why Neabeans issued this warning.

Comment: -1 for using that killerbee tutorial which is **AWFUL**

Comment: @Gil - ouch !!! what a silly mistake I have made. I wasted more than 3 hours on this, but finally got it. Many thanks for the help

Comment: We've all been there :)

Comment: @Your Common Sense - I cannot agree with the downvote, because so many beginners have commented on the site saying that it is really useful. It may not be the best technique to implement CRUD operations. But for a beginner it helps a lot.

Comment: They are beginners. So, their opinion don't count. In fact they learn WORST possible practices.

Comment: @Your Common Sense- yes for a beginner to understand CRUD operations it helps a lot. BTW thank you for your opinions.

Comment: This is not "opinion".

Comment: @Your Common Sense - Thanks for your advices :). Did not want to argue with or offend anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I have change your `PHP code` to below code use in your `edit.php`.if u get any issue put comment.

```
    <?php
include_once './functions.php';
include_once './database.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $firstName = cleanData($_POST['firstname']);
            $lastName = cleanData($_POST['lastname']);
            $age = (int) $_POST['age'];
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $query = "UPDATE basic ";
            $query.="SET first_name='$firstName',last_name='$lastName',age=$age ";
            $query.="WHERE id=$id";

            $r=mysql_query($query);
            if($r)
            {
                echo "Record updated";
            }

        }




            $id=$_GET['id'];

            $query="SELECT * FROM basic WHERE id='$id' ";
            $result=confirmQuery($query);

            $rows=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $firstName=$rows['first_name'];
            $lastName=$rows['last_name'];
            $age=$rows['age'];          


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Edit</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="edit.php" method="post">
            First Name<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstName ;?>"><br/>
            Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastName ;?>"><br/>
            Age<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $age ;?>"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
            <a href="main_menu.php">Cancel</a>


        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code too. But previously entered values are not shown :(. I cleared my cache too. BTW thank you

Comment: after clicking edit link your page should redirect to this page if yes then echo the $_GET["id"] and see the value is showing or not

Comment: @user3364940Your- Now it works. Thank you. I guess as Gil said the problem was with echo statements.